# Example of a function

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function like that
f(x,y)  not equal to f(y,x) 
for all integers and result must be integer also.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Impossible because, for any integre $n$, the equality $f(x=n,y=n)=f(y=n,x=n)$ is in contradiction to the condition $f(x,y)$ not equal $f(y,x)$.

Comment: Thanks correcting me actually i found solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you avoid the problem that $f(x,x)=f(x,x)$, how about $f(x,y)=x-y$?